# Store the past user entered commands into a linked list

Tags: c, arrays, input, linked-list

I have a program that reads in the users input into a char array called `inputBuffer` and also stores the length of the char array:

```
length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, 80);
```

I want to be able to store the past 10 inputs so they are accessible. When the 11th input comes in, I need to remove the first input so now only inputs 2-11 are stored. Can this be done with a linked list somehow?

Comment: Sure, you can do that with a linked list.  Give it a try, and if you get stuck post a more specific question including your linked list code.  Also look at a circular buffer.  That is a specialized kind of data structure probably more appropriate to this task. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses a ring buffer of structs that hold the string and the length, as OP asked for. When the buffer wraps, the previous string memory is freed and the new record initialised. The oldest record is at index `first_rec` and there are `num_recs` records. My main loop end test is when there is a blank entry, for the sake of this example. I was slightly lazy in the initialisation, assuming that the static array has string pointeres initialised to `NULL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define RECORDS 10
#define BUFSIZE 999

typedef struct {
    int length;
    char *input;
    } inpstruct;

inpstruct history [RECORDS];
int first_rec;
int num_recs;

void show_history (void) {
    int i, index;
    for (i=0; i<num_recs; i++) {
        index = (first_rec + i) % RECORDS;
        printf("Index: %-2d Length: %-3d Input: %s\n", index, 
                history[index].length, history[index].input);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char buffer [BUFSIZE+1];
    int len, index;
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
        len = strlen(buffer);
        if (len && buffer[len-1]=='\n')
            buffer [--len] = 0;             // truncate newline
        if (len == 0)
            break;
        index = (first_rec + num_recs) % RECORDS;
        if (history[index].input != NULL)   // release previous record
            free (history[index].input);
        if ((history[index].input = malloc(len+1)) == NULL) {
            perror ("malloc() failure");
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy (history[index].input, buffer);
        history[index].length = len;
        if (num_recs < RECORDS)
            num_recs++;
        else
            first_rec = (first_rec + 1) % RECORDS;
        show_history();
    }
    return 0;
}
```